# Filtering by count column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

ProductGroup

```
ProductGroupID  Description  
301             Shampoo         
302             Soap
303             Brush
```

Product

```
ProductID   ProductGroupID   Desc        Price
4001        301              Shampoo1    2
4002        301              Shampoo2    3 
4003        301              Shampoo3    4
4004        302              Soap1       2
4005        302              Soap2       3
4006        302              Soap3       5
4007        303              Brush1      6 
4008        303              Brush2      7
4009        303              Brush3      8
```

Order

```
OrderID     ProductID  
50001       4001 
50002       4002 
50003       4002 
50004       4002 
50005       4003 
50006       4007 
50007       4009 
50008       4003 
50009       4001 
50010       4005 
50011       4008 
50012       4009
```

Without Filtering

```
Select p.ProductID, p.Desc, pg.ProductGroupID, pg.Description  Count(o.ProductID) as OrderNum, p.Price
From Order o
inner join Product p
ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
inner join ProductGroup pg
ON p.ProductGroupID = pg.ProductGroupID
Group By p.ProductID, p.Desc, pg.ProductGroupID, pg.Description, p.Price with Cube
Having ProductGroupID is not null 

ProductID  Desc        ProductGroupID  Description OrderNum   Price
4001       Shampoo1    301             Shampoo     2          2
4002       Shampoo2    301             Shampoo     3          3
4003       Shampoo3    301             Shampoo     2          4
--------   --------    301             Shampoo     7          ----
4004       Soap1       302             Soap        0          2
4005       Soap2       302             Soap        1          3
4006       Soap3       302             Soap        0          5
--------   --------    302             Brush       1          ----
4007       Brush1      303             Brush       1          6
4008       Brush2      303             Brush       1          7
4009       Brush3      303             Brush       2          8
--------   --------    303             Brush       4          ----
```

---

With filtering in subtotal

```
Select p.ProductID, p.Desc, pg.ProductGroupID, pg.Description  Count(o.ProductID) as OrderNum, p.Price
From Order o
inner join Product p
ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
inner join ProductGroup pg
ON p.ProductGroupID = pg.ProductGroupID
Group By p.ProductID, p.Desc, pg.ProductGroupID, pg.Description, p.Price with Cube
Having ProductGroupID is not null 
AND SubTotal(OrderNum) =>  4 -- not working

ProductID  Desc        ProductGroupID  Description OrderNum   Price
4001       Shampoo1    301             Shampoo     2          2
4002       Shampoo2    301             Shampoo     3          3
4003       Shampoo3    301             Shampoo     2          4
--------   --------    301             Shampoo     7          ----
4007       Brush1      303             Brush       1          6
4008       Brush2      303             Brush       1          7
4009       Brush3      303             Brush       2          8
--------   --------    303             Brush       4          ----
```

How I will filter with their subtotals?

Comment: Use [`ROLLUP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: there is a typo int the code "without filtering": the subtotal of "Soap" has "Brush" in the description column. CUBE and ROLLUP are ok, but i prefer GROUPING SETS as in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29312/Grouping-Sets-in-T-SQL-SQL-Server-2008 as they allow precise configuration. ROLLUP and CUBE just use those under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which subtotals you want, you could either use the `ROLLUP` or `CUBE` operators.

Rollup will give you a hierachy of subtotals.  (I am assuming that `ProductID` and `Desc` have a 1:1 match so I have concatenated them in the rollup, the same goes for the Group ID and description).  I'm also assuming that you probably want products grouped within product groups.

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP((pg.ProductGroupID, pg.Description), (p.ProductID, p.Desc), p.Price)
```

Or you could use the cube operator to get all possible totals and subtotals.

```
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.Desc, pg.ProductGroupID, pg.Description, p.Price WITH CUBE
```

You can also use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(...` to specify all the groupings you want manually.

There are further examples [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

Comment: How about filtering with their subtotals?

Comment: You have to cross join with another query that produces the sub-totals, as mrtig does. The `having` clause by itself would only return the subtotal rows.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to filter an aggregated value. 
1. Use `HAVING` instead of the last `WHERE` clause:

```
Select p.ProductID, p.Desc, pg.ProductGroupID, pg.Description  Count(o.ProductID) as OrderNum, p.Price
From Order o
inner join Product p
ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
inner join ProductGroup pg
ON p.ProductGroupID = pg.ProductGroupID
Group By p.ProductID, p.Desc, pg.ProductGroupID, pg.Description, p.Price
HAVING COUNT(OrderNum) =>  4
```

Since this is for SQL 2008 R2, You can use `WITH CUBE` to get the subtotal:

```
Select 
    p.ProductID, 
    p.[Desc], 
    pg.ProductGroupID, 
    pg.Description, 
    Count(o.ProductID) as OrderNum, 
    p.Price
From 
    Order o
    inner join Product p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
    inner join ProductGroup pg ON p.ProductGroupID = pg.ProductGroupID
Group By 
    p.ProductID, 
    p.[Desc], 
    pg.ProductGroupID, 
    pg.Description, 
    p.Price
with cube
```

To grab a particular section based on some filter value you can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        Select 
            p.ProductID, 
            --p.[Desc], 
            --pg.ProductGroupID, 
            pg.Description, 
            Count(o.ProductID) as OrderNum, 
            p.Price
        From 
            Order o
            inner join Product p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
            inner join ProductGroup pg ON p.ProductGroupID = pg.ProductGroupID
        Group By 
            p.ProductID, 
            --p.[Desc], 
            --pg.ProductGroupID, 
            pg.Description, 
            p.Price
        with cube
    ) subTotals
    inner join 
    (
        SELECT Count(o.ProductID) as OrderNum, pg.Description
        FROM 
            Order o
            inner join Product p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
            inner join ProductGroup pg ON p.ProductGroupID = pg.ProductGroupID
        GROUP BY pg.Description
        HAVING Count(o.ProductID) >= 4
    ) groupFilter on groupFilter.Description = subTotals.description 
where Price IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for `with cube`. Still have a problem with filtering

Comment: What are you interested in seeing? Only the sub totals? or the entire segment where the subtotal is greater than some value?

Comment: The entire segment where the subtotal is greater than some value.

Comment: It giving the right result(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f7ec/1) but when I add other columns in the select the result is wrong(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f7ec/5)

Comment: When you add more columns to group by you add more subtotal sections, that's why you see the extra rows, if you don't want to see those, just filter out null prices.

Comment: The subtotal is missing

Comment: You need to use `with cube` instead of `with rollup` (realize I posted it in that way, corrected) and filter on Price IS NULL. I updated the answer.